# how can i dowload react native Component file without using url as PDF formate

Tags: react-native, pdf, react-native-pdf

> I am trying to create and download react-native component as  pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

[react-native-html-to-pdf](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf) you can create pdf file

[react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf) you can display pdf file